# How do I manipulate strings to store parts of them as variables?

Tags: c

I have a txt file that contains a bunch of information that my program needs to read from eg.

- Port: 1337
- IP: "IP"
- Directory: " "

I need to be able to store everything past the ": " from each line and save the part of the string as a variable eg. int port = 1337, something like that???

What functions should I use and how do I format this in order for it to work with as little code as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [fscanf()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanf-and-fscanf-in-c-simple-yet-poweful/). So long as the input is *always* properly formatted, it'll fill in the variables for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strtok` and `strtol` functions for this (if you're reading from strings):

```
int port = 0;
char *tmp_str;
strtok(port_str, ": ");
tmp_str = strtok(NULL, ": ");
port = strtol(tmp_str, NULL, 10);
```

etcetera.

Otherwise, use `fscanf` formatted input:

```
fscanf(file_pointer, "%*s%d", &port);
fscanf(file_pointer, "%*s%s", ip_str);
fscanf(file_pointer, "%*s%s", dir_str);
```

The `*`s in the format specifiers tell `fscanf` to ignore the string read ("Port", "IP", "Directory", etc.) and then the `:` (colon + space) tells `fscanf` to ignore the colon and any whitespace after it. Then `fscanf` reads an integer or a string (`%d` or `%s`, respectively) into the parameter passed to `fscanf`.

Comment: Can you explain the fscanf method a little bit more?

Comment: But using (negated) scan sets could work: `"%*[^:]: …"` would work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True. Does that still work with the `*`?

Comment: Would I have a while loop to look through the entire file or is there a way I can specifically target the line in the file?

Comment: A `while` loop would probably be the way to do it.